# Parse random number of recipients in log file by Grok

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a log like:

```
2019-05-23 16:33:54 +0300 08 mail SMTP-IN:0003ACBE: New mail <0000> received from mail.contoso.com (127.0.0.1) with envelope from <user@contoso.com>, recipients=3 (user1@contoso.com, user2@contoso.com, user3@contoso.com), size=1234, enqueued with id 12345
```

I looked at kv filter, but did not understand how to apply it, since the address pattern also falls on the sender.

I don't understand how to parse line like this. Recipients may be a random number. I want to get structured data by grok like:

"email1": "user1@contoso.com"

"email2": "user2@contoso.com"

"email3": "user3@contoso.com"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grok all the email addresses into one field and then use the [mutate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-split) filter to split them into an array.

If you really need to make new fields out of each one, you'd probably need to drop into ruby and loop across the array.